# Unable to run Thread programme

Tags: java

I am writing a simple program to explain thread.

Why does it show me the below errors.
Can anyone help me please.

```
public class Myth extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    int val=65;
    try {
      for(int i=0;i<26;i++) {
        System.out.println((char)val);
        val++;
        sleep(500);
      }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    // error pops up on this bracket saying class interface or enum expected.
    // error in this line says-- illegal start of expression

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Myth obj=new Myth();
      obj.start();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And this year's question formatting award goes to... YOU!

Comment: Sorry about the stupid formatting.Did it in a hurry. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *balance* the pair of opening and closing `curly` braces.

```
public class Myth extends Thread{
 public void run(){
   int val=65;
   try{
       for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
         System.out.println((char)val);
         val++;
         sleep(500);
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
       System.out.println(e);
    }
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
    Myth obj=new Myth();
    obj.start();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `run()` method isn't closed properly. Add an extra closing accolade after `System.out.println(e);` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot mthmulders it really helped.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks A Lot For Your help mthmulders

Answer (score 0):

Below is corrected code reason is your `run` method's body is not closed.

```
public class Myth extends Thread {

public void run() {

    int val = 65;
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            System.out.println((char) val);

            val++;

            sleep(500);

        }

    }

    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) // error in this line says-- illegal
                                        // start of expression

{
    Myth obj = new Myth();
    obj.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot amicngh.Your post helped.

Answer (score 0):

The `main` method was placed inside the `Myth.run()` method. Where as it should not be a static function of a class.

```
public class Myth extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        int val=65;
        try {
            for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
            {
                System.out.println((char)val);
                val++;
                sleep(500);
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        // error pops up on this bracket saying class interface or enum expected.
        // error in this line says-- illegal start of expression

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Myth obj=new Myth();
        obj.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Talha Ahmed Khan for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your run method is not properly closed by curly braces. Close and compile it, then it should be fine. It is a good practice to close the curly braces whenever you open one. Then you start writing the code in between them. That should help you to avoid this type of embarrassing silly mistakes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sakthisundar for the help